# keep random list elements and remove the others

Tags: python, list

I have a larg list of elements:

list=  [a1, b, c, b, c, d, a2, c,...a3........]

And i want to remove a specific elements from it a1, a2, a3
suppose that i can get the indexes of the elements start with a

```
a_indexes = [0,6, ...]
```

Now, i want to remove most of these elements start with a a but not all of them, i want to keep 20 of them chosen arbitrary. How can i do so ?

I know that to remove an elements from a list list_ can use:

```
list_.remove(list[element position])
```

But i am not sure how to play with the a list.

Comment: do you mean remove all items in bend_indexes except 20 randomized items?

Comment: @jose_bacoy As bend_indexes is a list contains an elements positions in the ring list, so my goal is to remove these elements except 20 randomized from ring list... so to solve it i think i need the indexes of the elements i want to remove, is it  right ?

Comment: Can you please provide an accurate example? Not a single of those code blocks is unambiguous Python code. If the weird types and values of `ring`/`bend_indices`/... don't matter, please replace them with standard ones; if they do matter, please define them properly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I edited my example with a simple one

Comment: What is `A`? What do the values in `a_indices` represent? Which of the lists do you want to remove elements from?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi a_indices list contains the positions of element a in the list (list), i want to remove most of the elements (a) from (list)

Comment: What does `a_indices` matter, then? If you just want to remove all but n elements, you don't need indices. What do you mean by the parenthesised thing - "(a)", "(list)" - especially in the question? Does the "(a)" relate to the "a" at the first position of the list?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In my actual example i deal with a's in different way, they have different names but i can get their indices using the a list so i cant remove a directly, the parenthesised  has nothing to do i just use them for more clarifications

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of original data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a an approach that will work if I understand the question correctly.

We have a list containing numerous items. We want to remove some elements that match a certain criterion - but not all.

So:

```
from random import sample
li = ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a']
dc = 'a'
keep = 1 # this is how many we want to keep in the list

if (k := li.count(dc) - keep) > 0: # sanity check
    il = [i for i, v in enumerate(li) if v == dc]
    for i in sorted(sample(il, k), reverse=True):
        li.pop(i)

print(li)
```

Note how the sample is sorted. This is important because we're popping elements. If we do that in no particular order then we could end up removing the wrong elements.

An example of output might be:

```
['b', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: @Lancelto Can i use the element indices to perform the same thing ?

Comment: @ely66 If you have a list of indices that you want to remove from a list (pop) then make sure you use them in descending numerical order

Comment: could you please give an example for this ?

Comment: @ely66 That's exactly what's happening in this answer

Comment: I meant to replace 'a' in dc with elements positions

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this list:

```
li=['d', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'g', 'b', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'e', 'f', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'f', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'd', 'b', 'e']
```

You can define a character to delete and a count `k` of how many to delete:

```
delete='a'
k=3
```

Then use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to generate a random group of `k` indices to delete:

```
idx=[i for i,c in enumerate(li) if c==delete]
random.shuffle(idx)
idx=idx[:k]
>>> idx
[3, 7, 31]
```

Then delete those indices:

```
new_li=[e for i,e in enumerate(li) if i not in idx]
```

Comment: This could work but it's not guaranteed. Consider what could happen if li=['a','b','a','b','a'] and k=3. di could be equal to [4,4,2] in which case only 2 elements would be removed

Comment: @LancelotduLac: Good point. Fixed